# Jquery or CSS selector to removing a padding in special case

Tags: jquery, css

I have some dynamically generated div with id = myFavDiv and class = myFavdiv and this is shared across many screens in my application. The css for myFavDiv (ID selector) looks like below.

```
#myFavDiv {
margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

However, I have a particular div with id = "salesTotal" and within this I have the myFavDiv being generated dynamically.  However, in this special case i.e when the 'myFavDiv' appears inside of 'salesTotal' div, the margin causes a layout issue.

Is there a CSS way to handle / manipulate the margin to be 0 (for the 'myFavdiv') by some kind of selector which would say something like - 'only when 'myFavDiv' appear withing 'salesTotal', set the padding to zero. Also, please note that 'myFavDiv' is not directly inside 'salesTotal'.

I am also okay with some Jquery way to manipulate this css.

I cannot change the CSS above because it would wrong affect many other places in the application.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Did you want the padding set to 0 on myFavDiv or on salesTotal? My answer below will set the padding to 0 on myFavDiv; if you want it to be 0 on salesTotal, it'll take jQuery, and I can delete that answer.

Comment: You want to set the padding = 0 or the margin?

Comment: Thanks for your response and Sorry for the confusion earlier. I want to set the margin = 0. Will be editing the original post as well.

Comment: Hi Matt, I want to set the margin to be 0 for myFavDiv

Answer (score 2):

You'd just add a second rule with a descendant selector:

```
#salesTotal #myFavDiv {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also, a bonus: You can replace your existing code with:

```
#myFavDiv {
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

You don't need the `px` after a 0 value, and if you have the same top/bottom and left/right, you can cut out the second set of values (so, `0 20px` actually ends up being read by the browser as `0 20px 0 20px`).

To make it clear, your final code should be:

```
#myFavDiv {
    margin: 0 20px;
}

#salesTotal #myFavDiv {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Matt, thanks much. I tried it and it didn't work. For the above solution to work , in the HTMl - does the myFavDiv need to be directly inside the salesTotal div. In my case, it is not.

Comment: @user1006072: It does not. As long as it's somewhere within `#salesTotal`, it's fine.

Comment: @user1006072 I've adjusted the code per your clarifications: it now clears the margin on #myFavDiv instead of the padding.

Comment: #salesTotal #myFavDiv ? "Id" are unique (supposedly), so this is not necesary

Comment: @MCSI It's not the best way to write semantic code, but it is the only way to achieve the OP's request: target *only* #myFavDiv which is within #salesTotal. Like you said, they're "supposedly" unique--but it's not uncommon for ids to end up in different contexts depending on the page.

Comment: yes but if you can manage different ID's, you can add diferent classes also